# Why doesn't my line match my barchart?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to create a chart that has both a line and a bar chart representation of an expression.  Because I'm using the same expression twice, I expect the line and the bar chart to match, but they are slightly off.

```
c = Plot[1000 (1 + 0.12/4)^(4 x), {x, 0, 12}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 7000}}]
d = BarChart[Table[1000 (1 + 0.12/4)^(4 x), {x, 0, 12, 1}]]
Show[c, d]
```

I can't figure out why this would be.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you on the right track:-

```
c = Plot[1000 (1 + 0.12/4)^(4 x), {x, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 7000}}];
 d = BarChart[Table[1000 (1 + 0.12/4)^(4 x), {x, 1, 12, 1}]];
 Show[d, c]
```

[image]